# converting to to key value pairs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is the object I have

```
    const upToPaidCost = [ { 'Labour Cost': '54000' }, { 'Material Cost': '24900' } ];
    let arr = [];


    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(...upToPaidCost)) {
        arr.push({ key: key, value: value });
    }
    console.log(upToPaidCost)
    console.log(arr);
```

Expected output :

```
    [
        {
          key: "Labour Cost",
          value: 54000
        },
        {
          key: "Material Cost",
          value: 24900
        }
    ]
```

It shows only the first key value, the second is missing, what am I making wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see, each item in the original array is an object. So you can do this way instead of iterating.

Besides, according to the expected output, value is a number. So you can cast from string to number like this.

```js
const upToPaidCost = [ { 'Labour Cost': '54000' }, { 'Material Cost': '24900' } ];

const result = upToPaidCost.map(o => {
  const [key, value] = Object.entries(o)[0];
  return {key, value: +value};
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, `Object.entries` takes a single object, and you've got an array of them. That's why you need two loops here:

```js
const upToPaidCost = [ { 'Labour Cost': '54000' }, { 'Material Cost': '24900' } ];
let arr = [];


for (const obj of upToPaidCost) {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
        arr.push({key, value});
    }
}

console.log(arr);
```

or two nested `map`s:

```
arr = upToPaidCost.flatMap(obj =>
    Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => ({key, value})))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to do it

```js
const upToPaidCost = [ { 'Labour Cost': '54000' }, { 'Material Cost': '24900' } ];
let arr = [];

const updatedArr = upToPaidCost.map((item)=>{
  return {"key":Object.keys(item)[0],"value":item[Object.keys(item)[0]]}
})



console.log(updatedArr)
```

Test in this link https://replit.com/join/taxflvkp-gauthamjm007

Comment: FYI, you can make runnable snippets right here.

Answer (score 0):

I like my codes to be more readable. Alternative answer.

```js
const upToPaidCost = [ { 'Labour Cost': '54000' }, { 'Material Cost': '24900' } ];
let arr = [];

const final = upToPaidCost.map((item)=>{
  const key = Object.keys(item)[0]
  return { key, value: item[key] }
})

console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Object.entries(...upToPaidCost)` is equal to `Object.entries({ 'Labour Cost': '54000' })`, so the result is wrong.

We need to combine the objects with the reduce method first:

```js
const upToPaidCost = [{ "Labour Cost": "54000" }, { "Material Cost": "24900" }];
let arr = [];
const conbineObj = upToPaidCost.reduce(
  (res, item) => ({ ...res, ...item }),
  {}
);
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(conbineObj)) {
  arr.push({ key: key, value: value });
}
console.log(upToPaidCost);
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Why your snippet works like this?

In this line

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(...upToPaidCost))
```

You are spreading `upToPaidCost` and then ask `Object.entries` to return it as an array-like.

so technically it's like this :

```
Object.entries({ 'Labour Cost': '54000' }, { 'Material Cost': '24900' })
```

as you see, you are passing 2 objects(arguments) to the `Object.entries`, which accept only one of them (the first one)

So this line will be interpreted like this

```
for (const [key, value] of [['Labour Cost': '54000']])`
```

## How to correct the snippet?

you could replace `Object.entries(...upToPaidCost)` to `Object.entries(upToPaidCost)` so the `Object.entries` only get one simple argument

and then in the for loop, you can push each object to the `arr`

you can check it out here:

```js
const upToPaidCost = [ { 'Labour Cost': '54000' }, { 'Material Cost': '24900' } ];
    let arr = [];

    for (const [arrayindex, innerObject] of Object.entries(upToPaidCost)) {
        arr.push(innerObject);
    }
    console.log(upToPaidCost);
    console.log(arr);
```

As you can see, the values are still string, if you are up to turn them to the number, you can get the key and value and make new objects and push them to the `arr` like this:

```js
const upToPaidCost = [ { 'Labour Cost': '54000' }, { 'Material Cost': '24900' } ];
let arr = [];

        for (const [upToPaidCostIndex, innerObject] of Object.entries(upToPaidCost)) {
            const key = Object.keys(innerObject)[0];
            const value = Object.values(innerObject)[0];
            
            arr.push({[key] : +value});
        }
        console.log(upToPaidCost);
        console.log(arr);
```

## Better solution

```js
const upToPaidCost = [ { 'Labour Cost': '54000' }, { 'Material Cost': '24900' } ];
const upToPaidCosts = upToPaidCost.reduce((res, item) => ({...item, ...res}), {});
const arr = Object.entries(upToPaidCosts).map(([key, value]) => ({[key]: +value}))


console.log(upToPaidCost);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score -1):

Here `Object.entries(...upToPaidCost)` remove ... 
Use ... when you want to copy an object like: `const x = {...upToPaidCost};` 
Or use `Object.entries({...upToPaidCost})` for your case